# Not able to show errors with Ember 2

Tags: ember.js

In an application built with Ember 2.1.0, I followed [this guide](http://alexspeller.com/server-side-validations-with-ember-data-and-ds-errors/) to implement server side validation.

I have this route :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('user', params.id);
  },
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      this.controller.model.save().then(function() {
        this.transitionTo('admin.users');
      }, (data) => {
        console.log(data.errors);
        this.set('errors', data.errors);
      });
    },
    cancel: function() {
      this.controller.model.rollbackAttributes();
      this.transitionTo('admin.users');
    }
  }
});
```

And I have this code in the template :

```
  {{#if errors.length}}
    <div class='alert alert-danger'>
      <h4>There was a problem</h4>
      <p>The user could not be saved due to validation errors</p>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
```

The server returns `{"errors":[{"email":["can't be blank"]}]}` and errors are displayed in the console but nothing on the page.

According to [the documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html), I tried to return `{"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"]}}` but I have "`InvalidError` expects json-api formatted errors array."

How can I show errors with Ember 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The data sent by the server was not using the json API format as written in [the doc](http://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects-basics) like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": "422",
      "source": { "pointer": "/data/attributes/first-name" },
      "title":  "Invalid Attribute",
      "detail": "First name must contain at least three characters."
    }
  ]
}
```

I wrote this code, in ruby, to format it correctly :

```
class ErrorSerializer
  def self.serialize(errors)
    result = errors.messages.map do |message|
      message.last.map do |detail|
        {
          "source": { "pointer": "/data/attributes/#{message.first}" },
          "detail": detail
        }
      end
    end.flatten
    { errors: result }
  end
end
```

I can be used like this :

```
render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: ErrorSerializer.serialize(user.errors)
```

Comment: Don't Active Model Serializers have the option to serialize resource errors in  a JSON API-ish way? I've stumbled upon this issue myself and I'm surprised we have to do this thing manually.

Comment: I see there's a pull request for said functionality: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/1004